# Howto Use Figure Placement 'H' in scrartcl

Tags: floats, scrartcl, figure-placement

How can I use the figure placement option 'H' from the `float` package (or some other way) within a `scrartcl` document?

I always get

```
! LaTeX Error: Unknown float option `H'.
```

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[version=last]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!H]
\includegraphics{something} \caption{some caption}\label{fig:something}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\begin{figure}[H]` without the `!` (which doesn't make sense for H floats).

Comment: Thanks.  That works fine!  Just in my defense: I got the `!H` from the 'official' documentation of the rmarkdown folk: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/figure-placement.html#prevent-figures-from-floating

Comment: that site is wrong can you report that there?

Comment: done here https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown-cookbook/issues/379